# Filling the holes for a concrete slab

Tags: repair, flooring, slab, hole-repair

There are two holes occured on 1st floor slab which are irregular in shape and able to see the ground floor which are having beams between it. How to fill those holes without disturbing the slab??? [image]

Comment: Are you sure those aren't deliberate, perhaps for drainage or resulting from a past repair of some sort? The area around them looks different from the rest of the floor, which could be erosion, deposition, or results of someone having deliberately modified this space.

Comment: Can you reach it in any way from the floor below?

Comment: It looks like it's damp....or was damp.   Maybe water was collecting there so someone added a few drain holes.

Comment: If that was intentional, it was halfassed.